# How do you use the partysplit function from partykit library to make a split with multiple factor levels in one child node

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am making a manual decision tree tool in R and am having trouble with categorical splits.

For a table `df` below I want to make a split on the variable `cat1` such that levels 1, 2, and 5 are in child 1 and levels 3, and 4 are in child 2

Is there a way to use `partysplit` to specify this?

```
df <- data.frame(cat1 = rep(c('A','B','C','D','E'), times = 100))

# This will give 5 child nodes with one level in each node
split1 <- partysplit(varid = 1L, index = 1:5)

# This gives an error because you have to specify index numbers from 1:number of child nodes

split2 <- partysplit(varid = 1L, index = c(1, 2, 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For categorical variables it is easiest to simply set `index` to the vector of node IDs each of the levels should go to. In your case:

```
split3 <- partysplit(varid = 1L, index = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L))
```

The function `character_split()` can then be used to extract the variable name and generate suitable labels. This is convenient for checking whether you got the split right:

```
character_split(split3, data = df)
## $name
## [1] "cat1"
## 
## $levels
## [1] "A, B, E" "C, D"
```